# Laravel recursive relationship return error in query

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

i have model Hobbies with these relationship

```
public function sub_hobbies(){
    return $this->hasMany(Hobbies::class, 'parent_id')->with('media');
}

public function allsub(){
    return $this->sub_hobbies()->with('allsub');
}
```

in my table hobbies i have data like this

```
id     name       parent_id
1      hobbie 1   null
2      hobbie 2   1
3      hobbie 3   2
```

with my query `Hobbies::with('sub_hobbies')->where('parent_id', null)->get();` i get the hobbies with sub_hobbies but there is the third stage, so when using `Hobbies::with('allsub')->where('parent_id', null)->get();` i except to have 3 stage of hobbies but i got error 500 without error message

i'm in laravel 8.75.0

**EDIT**
I found in my log that it make infinite sqlquery, i don't know why it behave like this, i use Mysql if there is something to do with it